# Обработка строк из файла

Tags: c

Есть текстовый файл, содержащий массив строк в следующем формате:

> name,88 46 5.9765,181 38 46.6695,84.972
>   ...
>   name,0 0 0.000,181 38 46.6695,84.972
>   ...
>   name,- 88 46 5.9765,181 38 46.6695,84.972

Нужно записывать числа в соответствующие переменные (например, в первой строке:
 88 в *x*, 46 в *y*, 5.9765 в *z*, 181 в *a*, 38 в *b*, 46.6695 в *c*, 84.972 в *h*). Если бы не было отрицательных значений, задача решалась бы просто (хранить числа не нужно):

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/home/Share/out_coord.txt", "r");
while (!feof(fp))
   fscanf(fp, "name, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", &x, &y, &z, &a, &b, &c, &h);
```

Как обрабатывать строки с минусом?

Comment: А есть объективные причины почему между минусом и числом присутствует пробел?

Comment: Дело в том, что текстовый файл создается в другой программе, которая создана не мной и изменить ее код я не могу.

Comment: Это строки с минусом или числа с минусом? В том смысле, что перед каждым числом может стоять минус?

Comment: В таком случае нужно либо читать как строки и склеивать для получения единого числа, либо подготовить файл ещё одной утилитой, которая уберет лишние пробелы.

Comment: Минус может стоять только перед первым числом.

Comment: В таком виде эти данные `fscanf()` все равно не прочтет (в соответствии с написанным форматом всюду между числами нужны запятые) / (правильно для запятых: `"name, %lf %lf %lf, %lf %lf %lf, %lf"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант (если представленные в вопросе данные отражают все их варианты),
 можно читать построчно, анализировать на минус в позиции 5 (после `name,`) и модифицировать строку

```
char line[LINELENGTH];

int pos = strlen("name,");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
   if (line[pos] == '-') {
      line[pos] = ' ';
      line[pos + 1] = '-';
   }
   sscanf(line + pos, "%lf %lf %lf, %lf %lf %lf, %lf",
          &x, &y, &z, &a, &b, &c, &h);
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Простейший способ, не требующий изменения кода,
но требующий изменения данных:

```
sed -i 's/- */-/g' /home/Share/out_coord.txt
```

После чего вызвать программу.

В некоторых случая намного проще подготовить (доготовить) данные чем встраивать в программу их обработку. Вы решаете задачу в два действия вместо того чтобы тратить уйму времени.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как именно изменятся данные в результате выполнения данной команды? Я просто совсем недавно познакомился с QNX)) И можно ли эту команду встроить в код программы?

Comment: @ratava: удаляются пробелы после минусов. Встроить можно, но если у вас минус только может быть в начале строки, то не знаю, стоит ли игра свеч. Проще просто смотреть первый символ в строке и всё. Но если всё же хотите встроить, то конечно без проблем: просто делаете exec

Comment: Тогда уж лучше запускать ее (только без -i) в `popen()` и читать выход.

Comment: @avp: Да, согласен